# Tensoring over dual numbers- Deformation theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

I am actually reading the course from Hartshorne about deformation theory. (https://math.berkeley.edu/~robin/math274root.pdf )
After having defined the notion of flatness about a module, the author then defines what the deformation of a closed subscheme of a given one is,  and begins with the affine case.

In this case, let $B$ be a $k$-algebra. And let's define $B' := B[t]/t^2$ and $D:=k[t]/t^2$

Let $I$ be an ideal of $B$, and $I' $ be one of $B'$ such that the image of $I' \subset B'$ onto $B'/tB'=B$ is exactly $I$.

My question is the following : why do we have in this case : 
$$B'/I' \otimes_D k = B/I$$
I tried to figure out on simple exemples but this fact seems weird to me. Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a module over $D$, $k = D/(t)$ so tensoring with it means killing $t$. This is exactly the assumption the previous sentence.

In more detail, you can apply the tensor with $k$ to the sequence $I’ \to B’ \to B’/I’$ and use right exactness and $B’\otimes k = B$ and $I’\otimes k = I$.

Comment: thank you for this answer it's clearer now